# How to get the incoming ssh/telnets clients local IP address from a shell script or C

Tags: c, scripting, ssh, client, ip-address

I need a way to obtain a local (not WAN) address of an incoming telnet or ssh 
session using a shell script or C.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done in several ways, depending on what OS/ssh daemon/telnet daemon you're using. Here are two approaches:

- OpenSSH publishes the clients ip (and ports) in the environment variable `SSH_CLIENT`. In bash, you can extract the IP with `${SSH_CLIENT%% *}`.
- Use the [utmpx](http://80386.nl/unix/utmpx/) database (the same as `who` uses), as explained here: [whoamIP - Find hostname/IP of current remote shell user](http://unixwiz.net/tools/whoamip.html), or using `last` like so: `last -i1 $USER | awk '{print $3;exit}'`

Comment: last -i1 $USER | awk '{print $3;exit}' always does not give correct result because it simply returns the last logged in user with same username. eg. if I log into the machine from different IPs and execute this command at the same time, all results won't be correct.